# How to remove element in mongodb array

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, meteor

How can I remove just one element of an array in a collection like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "Y9BBFa4c4vMiAkjbi",
    "metadata" : {
        "tags" : [
            "Anything",
            "Something",
            "More"
        ]
    }
}
```

In this example I just want to remove 'Something' - if it is existing.

```
var tag = 'Something';
if (Collection.find({ 'metadata.tags': tag }).count()) {
    Collection.update(
        { _id: id },
        { $pull: { 'metadata.tags': tag } }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure your `$pull`targets the array element you want to remove:

```
Collection.update({ _id: id },
    { $pull: { 'metadata.tags': { $eq: "Something" }}}
);
```